# Cross-platform way of yielding a thread in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, cross-platform, sdl

In C and C++ is there a cross-platform way of yielding a thread?
Something like sched_yield() or Sleep(0)?
Does SDL_Delay(0) always yield or will it return immediately in some implementations?

Comment: yield() is often a bad design. If you need to wait for something, then wait for it explicitly via an event, signal or condition of some kind.

Comment: Note that it's impossible to write a version of "yield" that will *always* yield. What if there's no other thread to yield *to*? I would say that SDL's SDL_Delay(0) does exactly what you want it to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given that neither C nor C++ (up to C++98) has "threads," there is no fully cross-platform way for a thread to yield.

In C++0x, there is a function `std::this_thread::yield()` that can be called to yield.  That will be the portable way for a thread to yield, once people start using the C++0x threads library.

Comment: I realize this isn't built into the language. I'm mainly wondering if there is a library available that does this, hence the comment about SDL_Delay.

Comment: @Shum: whatever threading library you're using likely has one. What threading library *are* you using?

Comment: @Shum:  As soon as you say "library" then the only answer is "maybe, it depends on what platforms the library supports and what functionality the library offers."

Comment: @Dean Harding: I'm using the SDL threading library but unfortunately it doesn't have one. I may use boost threads instead based on TokenMacGuy's answer.

Comment: @Shum:  Boost.Thread is a good choice for a reasonably portable threads library for C++.  If you want to be on the bleeding edge, [just::thread](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/) is a good commercial implementation of the C++0x threads library (it also happens to be written by the same person who wrote Boost.Thread, Anthony Williams).

Comment: @James McNellis: Thanks I'll look into those.

Comment: @Shum:  I would guess that Boost would support all of those.

Answer (score 4):

in the c++ case, [`boost::thread::yield()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.this_thread.yield) does what you ask.  On platforms with posix threads, [`pthread_yield()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_yield.3.html) performs the same function for C and anything that links with it.  On platforms where this doesn't immediately stop the thread and start another, it's because the scheduler doesn't support that functionality.  I don't think that many such platforms actually exist in the wild.

Comment: Yielding doesn't have to start another thread; the scheduler could immediately resume the thread that yielded.

Comment: @James: agreed, ambiguous wording, but considered from the perspective of time slicing schedulers, that line reflects that any new thread would still wait out the existing slice before having any chance of being scheduled, rather than commenting on whether another thread would really take its place.

Comment: On Windows (which of course does not have POSIX threads), one essentially calls `Sleep` with a time limit of 0 to yield.

Comment: in posix threading, the yielding thread is expected to be bumped to the bottom of the thread queue.  That would mean that if the current process has any threads that could possibly be scheduled, they would be scheduled in favor of the yielding thread.

Comment: Note that starting with Windows Server 2003, Sleep(0) does not yield the calling thread any more