# C++ Multi-Thread Execution Speed Slow-Down

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I am writing a multi-threaded c++ application. When thread A has a very computationally expensive operation to perform, it slows down threads B, C, and D. How can I prevent this?

Comment: How many cores does your system have? If you have less than 4 cores, then some cores will have to be shared among more than one thread, and that means that the cost of one thread will affect the others...

Comment: I have 4 cores. It is an intel i7.

Comment: 4 cores and one thread slows down the others? Either you aren't measuring correctly or the threads are logically locking each other (that is, it isn't the computation time slowing it down). Thus a `sleep` probably won't help.

Comment: Define: "It slows down threads B,C,D" How are you measuring this? 4 cores does not mean the application will run optimally with 4 threads. Remember the system is running a whole bunch of other processes each with its own threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On windows you can use `Sleep(0)` to release the remainder of your timeslice for other threads that are waiting.

Comment: This is what I would suggest - _but_ will slow down thread A so shouldn't be used if the computation is time critical

Comment: Given that he has 4cores it isn't possible for the CPU overhead of one thread to slow-down the others such that `sleep` would actually help.  He likely has some bad locking semantics. *false sharing is also possible, but it'd be difficult to notice with performance tests*

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing code so I can only give you the advice to lower Thread A's priority. This can be done using the [SetThreadPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can set the thread priorities ([`SetThreadPriority`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Also, I advice the backgroundworker picks it's work from a queue. The queue can then be used as a way to throttle the calculations:

- you can configure how many 'tasks' are taken from the queue for processing in one swoop
- you can lock the queue (use semaphores + condition event) so you can temporarily prevent new tasks from being picked up.
- you can now distribute the load across more workers (say if thread  B, C, D are temporarily idle, they can start to lift the work off thread A; very useful on a Quad-core + desktop)

$0.02

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways:

- As RedX suggested, add `Sleep(0)` in thread A's inner loop to have it yield time more frequently. This is the cheap and lazy solution.
- Better would be to change the thread priority. When you call `CreateThread`, pass `CREATE_SUSPENDED` so that the thread does not start immediately. Then call `SetPriorityClass` to set the thread to a lower priority, followed by `ResumeThread`.

Comment: With a lower priority it will be interrupted by other system processes aswell. With sleep(0) you can still have high-priority for all your threads and use Sleep to give the rest of your time to those threads. (Hope this makes sense)

Comment: @RedX, your comment is wrong. When you `Sleep(0)` the currently executing thread is suspended, but there's absolutely no guarantee that the next thread to run is from your process. So you're potentially yielding your time to system threads either way.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look at having your compute-bound thread yield the processor to other threads. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282773/cross-platform-way-of-yielding-a-thread-in-c-c) for various ways to do this.