# Cross platform way to prevent high cpu usage in while loop (Without boost)?

Tags: c++

I have a server that I want to run, and it uses a cross platform library that only gives me a tick() to call:

```
int main()
{
  Inst inst;
  while(true)
  {
    inst.tick();
  }
}
```

I need to try to lower the cpu usage so that it doesnt constantly take up 1 core.

Is there a simple way to do this without boost?

Thanks

Comment: Why without Boost? If you get an answer with Boost, you can look at how Boost does it, and then copy that, can't you? That still lets you avoid Boost as a dependency in your project, if that's the reason you don't want it.

Comment: You will need to use C++11, if you want to avoid boost libraries, by using `std::this_thread::yield()`. Courtesy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282773/cross-platform-way-of-yielding-a-thread-in-c-c

Comment: @ViteFalcon: `yield` won't reduce CPU usage, it will just make the process play slightly more nicely with others. The options are to sleep (if that doesn't cause unacceptable latency) or use a less broken library.

Comment: What does tick do? Do you need to call it in a tight loop, or is it ok to yield or sleep? What platform(s) are you targetting, and can you modify the thread priority?

Comment: I'd go with @MikeSeymour here - find a lib that is more multithread-friendly.  Some net stacks have a #define to turn on multithread opeations and OS interface code to go with it.

Comment: Well, what do you want to do instead of consuming CPU time? Most programs consume CPU time. What are your requirements?

Comment: I just called WINAPI sleep or posix yeild_thread for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //5 seconds
    auto duration = chrono::duration<float>(5);

    this_thread::sleep_for(duration);
    return 0;
}
```

However, even if this code is completely fine, I can't seem to compile it with the provided MinGW compiler from Code::Blocks.